# MongooseServerSelectionError

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, whitelist

> MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/ did not connect

This is the error I am facing. I have already tried adding my IP to network access but it doesn't work.

Already tried reconnecting and editing my IP and then connecting again but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please remove `mongoose-web-server` tag from the question

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to this problem as my connection had a dynamic IP and that's why it couldn't connect so anyone facing same problem as mine try clicking on the feature access from anywhere if you are also facing the same issue.